# Network working incorrectly on launch in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, updates

For the past few weeks I've noticed that apps that normally take a few seconds to check for updates when my PC starts take a lot longer. A few of these apps include things such as Discord, BattleNet, Origin, Steam and PHP Storm. I never used to have this issue in the past, the apps would take seconds to check. However now it seems pretty random, sometimes it will finish checking in two minutes, sometimes in an hour. As of now Steam has been checking for updates for the past hour.

I have connected my PC to the internet using the ethernet port from one of my Google Wifi mesh points. I am running the latest version of Windows 10 and have all the latest Windows updates (from the time of this post). I have also run a full scan using Windows Defender and have no issues (I doubt this information helps).

If you need any more information I will be happy to provide it.

ADDITION: My computer also seemed to start running slower when I started to get this issue. Things like delay when pressing start, Cortana search taking a long time to provide a result, unable to open some apps at all (E.g. BattleNet Client, Razer Synapse, Razer Cortex). Yes, I have run a optimize and defrag

ADDITION 2: Just as I shut down my computer it was interupted by an error, not sure if it's relevant: MediaContextNotificationWindow: ApCent.exe - Application Error The exception unknown software exception (0xe0434352) occurred in the application at location 0x00000000763918A2

ADDITION 3: Unsure if this is related but once I closed that error I got another: Task Host is stopping background tasks. (\Windows\DeviceDirecotryClient\RegistreUserDevice)

Comment: Please add these comments in your question. You can edit it. No need to reply this comment.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: I have run the test and read both articles but still do not understand them. Here is the output I got, @DavidPostill: https://pastebin.com/aDrjbPwD